# Laravel using word replacement in abort() error message with __() isn't working

Tags: laravel

I have an an abort(404) with a custom error message with translation and word replacement. But the word isn't replaced, instead it's showing the keyword that's supposed to be replaced.

```
abort(404, __('errors.no-category-of-type'), ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

And in errors.php

```
    'no-category-of-type' => 'There is no :foo category.',
```

This returns `There is no :foo category.`  instead of replacing the keyword.

I'm a bit surprised it's not working as it seems pretty straightforward and I just follow along what normally works fine of separately used language and abort functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `['foo' => 'bar']` on trans function as a second argument:

```php
abort(404, __('errors.no-category-of-type', ['foo' => 'bar']));
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I knew it had to be something simple yet I totally overlooked that one.